# How to partition a git commit in two, based on same parent?

Tags: git, branch, split, commit

I'm on branch foo, with parent A:

```
---A---foo
```

I want to partition the changes from A to foo into two branches, both
based on A. I believe I can do half the job like this:

```
git checkout -b halfFoo
git reset HEAD~
    # Only choose half the stuff.
git add -i
git commit
```

That gives me:

```
---A---foo
    \
     \-halfFoo
```

I know how to get it to this (git checkout -b otherHalfFoo; git commit -a):

```
---A---foo
    \
     \-halfFoo
      \
       \-otherHalfFoo
```

But what I'd like is to get this:

```
---A---foo
   |\
   | \-halfFoo
    \
     \-otherHalfFoo'
```

How can I do this without having to go through the 'git add -i' (and
selecting the negative of what was chosen for halfFoo) again?

Comment: There is no `git co` command. I'm assuming that's an alias for `checkout` based on its name and usage, but in the future, please use the full command, not your own custom alias.

Comment: @Cupcake: Thanks for pointing out my mistake, now fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, rewind to your previous commit, leaving in the changes since. Then branch off and apply some of the changes. Branch off from the original branch again, and apply the rest of the changes.

```
git branch original_tip_with_foo  # if you want a reference to the foo commit
git reset HEAD~
git stash
git branch branch_2  # we'll get there in a moment ...
git checkout -b branch_1
git stash pop
git add -p
# ... add your first set of changes, for the first branch ...
git commit -m'first set of changes'
git stash
git checkout branch_2
git stash pop
git add -p
# ... add your second set of changes ...
git commit -m'second set of changes'
```

Comment: Precisely what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is this:

```
git checkout -b branch1 foo
git rebase -i A
git checkout -b branch2 foo
git rebase -i A
```

When prompted, delete the lines that contain the commits you don't want and mark the ones you need to edit with an "e" instead of the "pick".

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding something, it seems that this technique will require me to go through all the changes twice, deleting and marking for the first branch, and then deleting and marking the opposite for the second branch. @wilhelmtell's solution appears to be more appropriate for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: his solution assumes you want to add everything as one commit in a patch. My approach will allow you to preserve the commits to make the 2 branches look exactly as you want, including history. You may be fine with his solution, but it would not work for others that want commits to be split into the 2 branches. This solution works for your end result too if you run git rebase -i A a second time and squash.

Comment: plus you can cut yourself with stash if you don't know how it acts when something is indexed, tracked but not indexed and not tracked at all.

Answer (score 0):

From your graphs, to get to the last image from the penultimate graph, checkout A again, create a new branch and cherry-pick otherHalfFoo. Then reset --hard the branch woth halfFoo to the correct commit (HEAD~1 probably).

Answer (score 0):

Use `checkout -i` to interactively select bits you want in one half, and commit that. Then use `git revert` on the branch with everything to remove what you split out.

From your example on branch foo, with parent A:

```
---A---foo
```

Create a new branch and interactively add the changes you want there:

```
git co -b halfFoo foo~
git checkout -i foo
git commit
```

That gives:

```
---A---foo
    \
     \-halfFoo
```

Then, easily create a branch that is foo without the items you selected for halfFoo by using `git revert`:

```
git co -b otherHalfFooWithHistory foo
git revert halfFoo

---A---foo
    \     \-otherHalfFooWithHistory
     \-halfFoo
```

Which is conceptually what you want for otherHalfFoo, but does have a history where all of foo existed and then some of it was removed. You can optionally clean it out with `merge --squash`:

```
git co -b otherHalfFoo foo~
git merge --squash otherHalfFooWithHistory
git branch -D otherHalfFooWithHistory

---A---foo
   |\
   | \-halfFoo
    \
     \-otherHalfFoo
```